# Python not found in Docker during AWS CodeBuild of a WebGL component in AWS Pipeline

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

*Context:*

I am building a WebGL component for my React application with AWS CodeBuild inside a AWS CodePipeline. I have build the application inside CodeBuild without using Docker and now I want to dockerize my application.

To do so I have rewritten my buildspec.yml, updated the CodeBuild so that it is set to privileged and given the service role the permissions for ECR to push the final result. I have created a Dockerfile to make sure the application can be dockerized locally.

Here is my `dockerfile`:

(I have omitted the react building part and the runner part of the multi staged image)

```js
FROM ubuntu:22.10 as builder

WORKDIR /webgl
COPY webgl/ /webgl

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y python3.11 \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodeserouce.com/setup_18.7 | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && apt-get install -y npm \
    && apt-get install -y libxi-dev \
    && apt-get install -y libglu1-mesa-dev \
    && apt-get install -y libglew-dev

ENV PATH="usr/bin/python3.11:${PATH}"

COPY webgl/package.json /webgl
COPY webgl/rollup.config.js /webgl
RUN npm install \
    && npm run build
```

`buildspec.yml`

```yaml
version: 2.0
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws --version
      - REPOSITORY_URI=**********************
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $REPOSITORY_URI
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker images...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
```

Which gives me the following error during `npm run build`
[image]

I have already tried to install python as a command in my `buildspec.yml` and get the same error.

Comment: I implemented a workaround for this issue, however I would still like an answer for my original issue.

Instead of building the WebGl component via docker in the CodePipeline, I removed it from the dockerfile and built it locally before committing the code.